# How do I install 13.10 beside 13.04 without using removable media?

Tags: installation, upgrade

How do I install 13.10 beside 13.04 without using removable media?

I have two partitions. One has 13.04 and the other is empty. I'd like to install 13.10 on the empty partition, but I don't have any removable media to create an install disk.

How do I run the network installer from my existing installation without overwriting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually make a bootable flash drive, instead of the traditional bootable disk! Now your most says you have no removable media, does this mean you have no flash drives?

In any event that you get a hold of a flash drive, there is a GUI you can use to make a bootable flash drive. Sorry at work right now and I can't think of what the program is called.

Let me know what happens!

Comment: I have a network! Why would I ever need removable media? ;)

Comment: I ended up buying a USB stick. :p

Answer (score 1):

I Believe this is what you are looking for:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromLinux

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: Anytime! Tell me if it worked:)

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. I ended up buying a USB stick.

Comment: sounds good!!! im sorry it didnt work :(